# 3.0.0.M1 how to run on https connection

Tags: grails, grails-3.0

Trying Grails 3.0.0.M1, a lot has changed!

How would I `run-app --https` and how would I configure it that way also for the production-environment-war?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, Grails 3.0.0.M1 is **not** production ready, if thinking about making the move.

Major changes for Grails 3 include:

- Built on top of Spring Boot
- Introduction of Gradle as the build system
- And many more (which is not relevant to this question)

In order to setup SSL for Spring Boot app, `server.ssl.*` setting has to be added to `application.properties` or `application.yml` file.

In Grails 3 it would correspond to `application.yml` under `grails-app/conf`. Below changes (as an example) would be required:

```
server:
  port: 8443
  ssl:
    key-store: classpath:keystore.jks
    key-store-password: secret
    key-password: another-secret
```

which is equivalent to [Configuring SSL in Spring Boot](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-embedded-servlet-containers.html#howto-configure-ssl).

However, documentation is limited right now and is being worked on. So let Grails 3 brew more until its GA where it can be used in production environment.

Grails community will be more than happy if any issues/problems/enhancement is reported in [Grails JIRA](https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS)

Comment: beginning with a new application and knowing, that grails 3.0 will be ready in 2 months... I don't want to begin with an old version and then migrate. Thanks

Comment: sorry to annoy you: with the above definition - in which directory would I put the keystore.jks file?

Comment: Should be on the classpath. `grails-app/conf` would be a place to add the keystore file.

Comment: Putting the keystore there I get the Errors statted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28366250/3-0-0-m1-ssl-invalid-keystore-format. But it works with keyStore: file:/absolute/path/to/keystore

Comment: Gr8. I don't think you need `classpath:keystore.jks`. Did you try just `keystore.jks` in the YAML file?

Comment: Without classpath it looks for the keystore in the root directory of the project. I suppose because this is the working directory for the grails shell and run-app (?)

Comment: Yes, correct. You can try that as well. Moving it to the root, it that does not bother you.

Comment: I have never yet deployed a real application. Would it remain also the root of the application under tomcat?